# Why do cats purr?

Tags: cats, vocalizations

There's many questions about [purring](https://pets.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=purring%20is%3Aquestion) and some questions about how much purring is normal.

[Why does my cat (almost) constantly purr while he's awake?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/914/why-does-my-cat-almost-constantly-purr-while-hes-awake)

[How much purring is too much purring?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/519/how-much-purring-is-too-much-purring)

What I want to know is why cats purr?

*I'm not looking for anecdotal answers, or opinions, I would like well-researched answers, citing reputable sources.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How much purring is too much purring?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/519/how-much-purring-is-too-much-purring)

Answer (score 3):

From Scientific America [Why do cats purr?](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/why-do-cats-purr/)

> If it’s a form of communication, it’s meant for those near and dear,
>   since cats purr at a frequency and volume too low to travel far.
>   Purring (and many other low-frequency vocalizations in mammals) often
>   are associated with positive social situations: nursing, grooming,
>   relaxing, being friendly.

From [Why Do Cats Purr? It’s Not Just Because They’re Happy](https://www.wired.com/2015/05/why-do-cats-purr/)

> More likely, though, purring is simply soothing, or self-soothing, as
>   cats may also purr in stressful situations. In that case, purring
>   would be akin to how humans soothe themselves by crying, laughing,
>   distracting themselves, or even organizing their desk. Some
>   veterinarians and cat enthusiasts have observed cats lying alongside
>   each other and purring when one is injured (a behavior termed “purr
>   therapy”), though scientific literature on the subject is scant.
>
> Beyond being calming for the injured kitty, “purr therapy” may have
>   bone healing properties. Domestic cats purr at a frequency of about 26
>   Hertz, in a range that promotes tissue regeneration. That’s not as
>   crazy as it sounds: High-impact exercise promotes bone health for the
>   same reason, because bones respond to pressure by making themselves
>   stronger.
>
> In their natural setting, cats spend a lot of time lying around
>   waiting to hunt, so purring may stimulate bones so that they don’t
>   become weak or brittle.